# Postgres: Parsing JSON data in sql

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to parse following json data and use it under the `where` clause.

```
Basic":{  
   "General":{  
      "Field1":1234,
      "Field2":"6.86"
   },
   "Stream 0":{  
      "Type":"LDAP",
      "Field4":"LALA1"
    },
    "Stream 1":{  
      "Type":"KERBEROS",
      "Field4":"LALA2"
    },
    "Stream 2":{  
      "Type":"SAML",
      "Field4":"LALA3"
    },
```

I can reach to `Type` tag like this.
`table.column_json::json->'Basic'->'Stream 0'->'Type'`

The order of `Stream #` is undefined and there could more than 3 `Stream` tags.

How can I iterate through each Stream and find if `Type:` is `"SAML"` then `Field4` value is `"LALA3"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple different keys you want to search through, you need to "unpack" the K/V pairs and then do string matching:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM table t, json_each(t.column_json::json->'Basic') j(k, v)
WHERE j.k LIKE 'Stream%'
  AND j.v->>'Type' = 'SAML'
  AND j.v->>'Field4' = 'LALA3';
```

Note that the `json_each()` function is PG9.3+.

Comment: `json_each()` worked for me but `=` are giving `operator does not exist` error. I tried using ` j.v->'Type'::varchar='SAML'` but no luck.

Comment: Ah, yes. It should have been the `->>` operator to get the field as `text`. See updated answer.